# npm package "aws-jwt-verify" not able to fetch jwks file on windows ec2 machine

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, amazon-cognito, aws-jwt-verify

We have an express project where we've created a route to verify our token using "aws-jwt-verify" npm package. This code was working properly fine on mac and linux machines but when for our staging environment we deployed this on windows ec2 machine using pm2 process manager this package was not working and throwing an error.

Code

```
const { CognitoJwtVerifier } = require('aws-jwt-verify');
class TokenVerificationSvc {
    constructor() {
    }

    async verify(token, type = 'id') {
        const docClient = new CognitoJwtVerifier({
            userPoolId: process.env.SApplicationUsersPool,
            tokenUse: type,
            clientId: process.env.SApplicationUsersPoolClient,
        });
        return await docClient.verify(token);
    }
}

module.exports = { TokenVerificationSvc };
```

Error

> Failed to fetch https://cognito-idp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com//.well-known/jwks.json: Response time-out (after 1500 ms.)`

To fix the above issues we tried another approach where we use the axios to fetch the jwks files and then cache that with our "aws-jwt-verify" for use. This is the same approach mentioned in "aws-jwt-verify" package documentation for reading files from filesystem.

Improvised Code

```
const { CognitoJwtVerifier } = require('aws-jwt-verify');
const axios = require('axios');
class TokenVerificationSvc {
    constructor() {
    }

    async verify(token, type = 'id') {
        const jwksResponse = await axios.get(`https://cognito-idp.${process.env.CLOUD_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${process.env.SApplicationUsersPool}/.well-known/jwks.json`)
        const docClient = new CognitoJwtVerifier({
            userPoolId: process.env.SApplicationUsersPool,
            tokenUse: type,
            clientId: process.env.SApplicationUsersPoolClient,
        });
        const jwks = jwksResponse.data;
        docClient.cacheJwks(jwks);
        return await docClient.verify(token);
    }
}

module.exports = { TokenVerificationSvc };
```

Now I want to understand if this is the right approach to implement this or if there is some other way to do the same not using axios or any other 3rd party request like package.

Comment: Encountering this same problem, did you manage to get it fixed?

Comment: related: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-jwt-verify/issues/72#issuecomment-1139609992