# Failed to fetch JWKs https://cognito-idp.#region.amazonaws.com/#region_#clientId/.well-known/jwks.json

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, amazon-cognito, aws-jwt-verify

I try to fetch aws-cognito JWKs using `aws-jwt-verify` npm package to verify JWT token but unfortunately it fails randomly.

I have node/express app which I deploy (entire app) to one lambda function. So basically app start as below for lambda function (production),

**server.js**

```
const awsServerlessExpress = require("aws-serverless-express");
const app = express();
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app)

const verifyToken = require("./src/middlewares/auth.middleware");   // auth middleware to verify token

app.use(`${api/products`, verifyToken, productsRoute);

// other routes     

if (NODE_ENV === "local") {                                         // for development
  const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    logger.debug(`node-express server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on ${PORT}`);
  });

} else {                                                            // For production
  module.exports.handler = (event, context) => {                    // For lambda execution start here
     awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context);
  }
}
```

**auth.middleware.js**

```
const { CognitoJwtVerifier } = require('aws-jwt-verify');
const { SimpleJwksCache } = require("aws-jwt-verify/jwk");
const { SimpleJsonFetcher } = require("aws-jwt-verify/https");


const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {                        // for requested route, it executes          
      const token = req?.headers?.authorization;
      let decodedToken;
       

      const verifier = CognitoJwtVerifier.create(
        {
          userPoolId: enviornment.cognito.userPoolId,
          tokenUse: 'id',
          clientId: enviornment.cognito.appClientId,
        },
        {
          jwksCache: new SimpleJwksCache({                              // I hope, I'm caching it so it doesn't end up fetching JWKs again n again. Correct me if my understanding is wrong
            fetcher: new SimpleJsonFetcher({
              defaultRequestOptions: {
                responseTimeout: 5000,
              },
            }),
          }),
        }
      );

      decodedToken = await verifier.verify(token);

      ...
      ...

      next();

}
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Can't tell exactly when it fails.

> Failed to fetch https://cognito-idp.#region.amazonaws.com/#region_#clientId/.well-known/jwks.json: response time-out (after 3000 ms.)

Similar question was never answered : [npm package "aws-jwt-verify" not able to fetch jwks file on windows ec2 machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76358913/npm-package-aws-jwt-verify-not-able-to-fetch-jwks-file-on-windows-ec2-machine)

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty short timeout at 3 seconds. As a quick change you might extend it by extending the [responseTimeout](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-jwt-verify?tab=readme-ov-file#configuring-the-jwks-response-timeout-and-other-http-options-with-jsonfetcher).

The wider problem is that a serverless lambda is created on every API request so is unable to use memory caching. This is a real downside of lamdbas.

By default every API request will call the JWKS endpoint, putting load on the authorization server, a critical component. Therefore you are responsible for preventing this. In fact it might be the cause of your problems.

You might do so by customizing the cache interface of your JWT library. I did a similar thing in a code example of mine that uses [JwksRetriever](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.serverless/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/jwksRetriever.ts) and a [DynamoDB cache](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.serverless/blob/master/src/plumbing/cache/awsCache.ts).

This code is pretty unpleasant but the API has been running reliably online (for a basic load) to support some [online code examples of mine](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/) for some years now.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree and you are pointed out rightly that with every API request, it is trying to fetch JWKs and Lambda container is created. I'd appreciate if you can help me with the library that I use. I know caching mechanism is there but the problem is with each API request, lambda container is created. Meanwhile I will check your provided references.

Answer (score 1):

You can cache elements of configuration for multiple parallel firing of a Lambda function: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-the-aws-parameter-and-secrets-lambda-extension-to-cache-parameters-and-secrets/

To do that use Lambda Extension, and allow all the request beyond the first one in the defined maximum cache time to benefit from a local read instead of a remote get. Keys have an id defined in the kid claim of a JWT header. Whatever Cognito creates or rotates a key, it will have a different kid value.

Therefore you can have the following sequence:

- JWKS Document fetching: If JWKS is accessible via cache -> use it; if not get it remotely and set the cache
- JWT Validation: If kid in JWKS document -> validate token; if not and document is from cache get it remotely, set the cache, and restart JWT validation; Otherwise (it means the JWKS documenthas been fetch but kid is not there), return unauthorized

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do Cogntio JWKs rotate ? I was searching online and didn't get any clue or documentation on it.

Comment: It can rotate if the we decide to create a new key for signing tokens, rotating an existing key, or revoking an existing key.
But even when rotating an existing key, we will create a new key as a consequence. So at the end of the day, your logic of caching should be based on the kid. If it is in the document cached, use it as is. If not fetch it.